# Why are some system recommendation questions being closed while others are not?

Tags: discussion, game-recommendation

[Are there any other Beer & Pretzel PnP games along the lines of Paranoia?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9812/are-there-any-other-beer-pretzel-pnp-games-along-the-lines-of-paranoia)  has been closed twice now, but [RPG designed for irregular players/gaming?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/9755/rpg-designed-for-irregular-players-gaming) is still open.  Can someone explain to me what the difference is?

Answer (score 4):

No one reads every question, so just because one question gets closed for cause and another doesn't does not mean the other question is a good question.

That other question is slightly better in that it is not specifically asking for a bunch of answers, it's asking for one, although it is indeed not giving much in the way of criteria to select a best one, so it could stand some guidance too.

You might consider giving them guidance, rather than coming here to narc them out to make someone else do it.

Comment: i'm just confused because both of these seem, to me, to follow the guidelines set here: http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-disallowed-on-rpg-se/1071#1071

Comment: "If your question is pulling a list and not a "best," it's a bad question." Beyond that specific meta question, it is well understood that lists are OT.

Comment: I have gone and put a shot across the bow of the "irregular" question too.

Comment: Isn't [tag:system-recommendation] inherently going to lead to many answers without one definitive "correct" answer? It's perhaps worth noting that on gaming.stackexchange, game recommendations are closed as not constructive. I can see the value of the questions, though.

Comment: @JonathanDrain yes, and gaming.SE's stance is explicitly taken into account in the guidance we linked when we hashed over this in the first place - http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1070/are-game-recommendation-questions-disallowed-on-rpg-se/1071#1071